# Linker Error : Statically Linking of Boost Serialization Library

Tags: c++, boost, linker

I'm trying to link the Boost Serialization Library to my Code. But it doesn't seem to be working.

g++ serialize.cpp -L"/usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.a"

Error :

/tmp/ccw7eX4A.o: In function `boost::archive::text_oarchive::text_oarchive(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int)':
serializep.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC2ERSoj[_ZN5boost7archive13text_oarchiveC5ERSoj]+0x25):
undefined reference to`boost::archive::text_oarchive_impl::text_oarchive_impl(std::basic_ostream >&, unsigned int)'
..........
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

But when i link as a shared library,
g++ serialize.cpp -lboost_serialization  , it works fine.

What am i missing here

P.S : Other StackOverflow posts with the same question has no answers that work for the above error

Comment: Static linkage performs using `-static` keyword. Also, -l* and -L"lib*.a" are the same things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> g++ serialize.cpp -L"/usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.a"

This command line is *totally* wrong: the `-L` flag tells the linker where to look for libraries; it does *not* tell the linker to use a library you are giving. Try this instead:

```
g++ serialize.cpp /usr/local/lib/libboost_serialization.a
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't reproduce your problem, the better I can do is to tell you how I generally compile against boost_serialization statically:

```
 g++ myapp.cpp -o myapp -Wall -static -static-libgcc -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_serialization -lpthread
```